# Monitor the start and end time of transferring files

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

Is it possible to automate transferring files from one computer to other computer and monitor the start time and end time and it can simultaneously transfer multiple files files(multi threading)? Is this possible thru automation anywhere metabot or any scripts i can run thru automation anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1):

As far as transfer of files goes, Yes, it's possible in a few ways. Actually, easiest way is with a simple task, metabots would be a bit of overkill for this unless you use a 3rd party application to access the other computer. Regarding the multi-thread, it depends on the way you implement the transfer. If you're just scripting it in then the bot will run the script from atmx line by line so no multi-thread there; you can do this type of multi-thread if you open 2 instance windows for transfer then just use tasks to actually start the transfer. (i.e. 2 putty windows where you set the command in each then loop back to execute it for each window. This is a crude example but it will give you the idea).

Comment: Thanks for answering Vlad, Same thought I been lurking on  my mind to use multiple instance of a window. I might try using robocopy thru cmd or power shell. What I foresee as a challenge is how to get end time of each fie when the execution of transfer of files all host in different cmd window?